# Azure Hybrid connection failed. Exceeds allowed amount

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up a hybrid connection with an Azure Function but I get the error: "Failed to add hybrid connection.  Adding a Hybrid Connection failed because it would exceed the allowed amount of 0 connections".

Where in Azure do I increase the number of hybrid connections?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Switch to a Basic or Standard App Service Plan first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hybrid Connections feature is only available in Basic, Standard, Premium, and Isolated pricing SKUs. There are limits tied to the pricing plan.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#hybrid-connections-and-app-service-plans).